# What is a Data warehouse in this use case

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, data-warehouse, data-processing

I'm trying to figure out the difference (between tools/services/programs) between  Data Warehouse, Clustered Data Processing and the tools/infrastructure for querying a Data Warehouse

So Let's say I have the following setup to perform some data processing for a certain use case

```
Hadoop Cluster for Distributed Data processing
Hive for providing infrastructure and Functions for querying data from a data warehouse
My data sitting in an RDBMS or a NoSQL database
```

In the above example, what exactly is the Data Warehouse? My naive brain thinks that it is the RDBMS or the NoSQL database in the above context is the Data warehouse. But by definition, isn't a Data warehouse a database used for reporting and data analysis? (Definition shamelessly stolen from Wikipedia). So can I call a traditional RDBMS/NoSQL database a Data Warehouse? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call every **relational database system** a data warehouse, since one of data warehouses main feature is to aggregate data from multiple databases (with different schemas). It is usually done with a "[star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)" allowing to combine multiple dimensions and multiple granularities.

Because **NoSQL database systems** (graph-based or map-reduce-based) are schema-less they can indeed store data from different schemas. Moreover Map-Reduce can be used to aggregate data with different granularities (e.g. aggregate daily data to compare them with monthly data).

Comment: Thank you. So can I use Neo4j or Mongo as a Data warehouse? Also you mentioned Map Reduce. Are you referring to the algorithm or a Map Reduce implementation like Hadoop? If so where does Hive fit it?

Comment: Also if I pull in data from a bunch of disparate RDBMS and use a Hadoop cluster to process it, What is the Data Warehouse in this context? Thanks.

Comment: I mentioned Map-Reduce because it is both quite common in NoSQL frameworks and it is a good way to aggregate data with different granularities. Some datastore have their own implementation of it (MongoDB, CouchDB), but nothing prevents you to use an external implementation of it (like Hadoop).

Comment: Where is the data warehouse? A simple answer could be: where you store data in their heterogeneity and where you process them homogeneously.

Comment: And yes, Hive is definitely one of the ways to do that.